# Merge two deep arrays

Tags: javascript

So I've got two infinitely deep arrays as seen below.

```
const one = [
    {
        name: 'CRISPS',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'salty crisps',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'CHOCOLATE',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'full sized bars',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    }
]

const two = [
    {
        name: 'CRISPS',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'salty crisps',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'DRINKS',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'fizzy drinks',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'CHOCOLATE',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'small sized bars',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like to be able to merge them so that I will get the outcome of

```
const three = [
    {
        name: 'CRISPS',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'salty crisps',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'CHOCOLATE',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'full sized bars',
                items: []
            },
            {
                name: 'small sized bars',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'DRINKS',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'fizzy drinks',
                items: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This merge will be the combination of the two arrays as well as only keeping the unique values of the items in the list.

I have an inclining that I will need to create a custom recursive function to merge these two, however I was hoping that there might be a premade solution to do this.

I've attempted with lodash's `_.merge()` However I was either using it wrong or it is not applicable.

**Edit** For lodash I attempted the standard `_.merge(one, two)` however this tended to not merge deeply. From there I've started looking at creating my own recursive method.

I've also updated the example to how how `CHOCOLATE` should merge.

Thanks!

Comment: const 3 = [...one, ...two ]; may be this will help you

Comment: My lodash attempts were not massively clever, it was basically just a stright attempt of `_.merge(one, two)` As I wasn't sure if it went deep or not. I'm still working on it now so will post updates.

Comment: @Osama That just creates a new array of [one, two] separately and not merged

Comment: I've added a bit more to the example to show how chocolate merges deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, a recursive function is the way to go. The idea is that we merge the lists at the top level, and if we find things to merge in `one` AND `two`, we recursively call merge on THEIR items:

```js
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
  let res = [];
  let arr2Index = arr2.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.name] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  // add all elements from arr1 to res after merging them with their common element in arr2
  arr1.forEach(i => {
    if (i.name in arr2Index) {
      i.items = merge(i.items, arr2Index[i.name].items);
      delete arr2Index[i.name];
    }
    res.push(i);
  });

  // add remaining objects from arr2 to res
  res.push(...Object.values(arr2Index));
  return res;
}

// Test

const one = [{
    name: 'CRISPS',
    items: [{
      name: 'salty crisps',
      items: [{
        name: 'very salty crisps',
        items: [{
          name: 'mega salty crisps',
          items: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'CHOCOLATE',
    items: [{
      name: 'full sized bars',
      items: []
    }]
  }
];

const two = [{
    name: 'CRISPS',
    items: [{
      name: 'salty crisps',
      items: [{
        name: 'very salty crisps',
        items: [{
          name: 'hi',
          items: [{
            name: 'somewhat salty crisps',
            items: []
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'DRINKS',
    items: [{
      name: 'fizzy drinks',
      items: []
    }]
  }
];

console.log(merge(one, two));
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I've created and seems to work from first testing. I'll mark as accepted when I've tested it a little more. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this method using spread operator:

```js
const one = [
    {
        name: 'CRISPS', items: [{ name: 'salty crisps',items: [] }]
    },
    {
        name: 'CHOCOLATE', items: [{ name: 'full sized bars', items: [] }]
    }
]

const two = [
    {
        name: 'CRISPS',  items: [{ name: 'salty crisps',items: [] }]
    },
    {
        name: 'DRINKS', items: [{ name: 'fizzy drinks',items: [] }]
    }
]

const merge = (p, ...arrs) => [...new Set([].concat(...arrs).map(a => JSON.stringify(a)))].map(a => JSON.parse(a));

const three = merge('name', one, two);

console.log(three);
```

thanks to this post: https://gist.github.com/yesvods/51af798dd1e7058625f4

Comment: So weirdly, I can see it works above, however running on my name code set it doesn't merge but just adds them to the same array. I'll continue testing thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry this doesn't work. I added an extra example to further show how it should merge with chocolate. I also attempted your answer here https://gist.github.com/jackdh/b78145fce2ce2f3231a88ca409641161